# How to update (save) a variable by post ID in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to update a variable that is getting recieved by a session. Now it will save the data but it is for every post the same. It needs to save the value by post id.

A part of the code is (*it's part of a Advanced Custom Field template*):

```
<?php
function create_field( $field ) 
{
$value = $_SESSION['updatevalueMax'];
echo '<div id="value">' . $value . '</div>';
}

    function update_value( $value, $post_id, $field )
    {
        return $value;

    }

?>
```

The update_value function is activated when a post is updated. How to make this work so the $value is updated by $post_id? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register the filter with Wordpress:

```
function my_plugin_update_value( $value, $post_id, $field )
{
    // Do something and update $value.
    return $value;
}
add_filter('acf/update_value', 'my_plugin_update_value', 10, 3);
```

Although in your example $value is just going to be what is sent into the function. I am not sure what you trying to update it with.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a filter in your functions.php

follow the url to better understand.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data